# How to apply stylesheet to a custom widget in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

        stylesheet = \
            ".QWidget {\n" \
            + "border: 20px solid black;\n" \
            + "border-radius: 4px;\n" \
            + "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n" \
            + "}"
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to add a border to a custom widget with stylesheet, but the stylesheet does not seem to work, anything wrong?

Comment: have you tried removing the period before QWidget?

Comment: although you did receive an answer that seems adequate, please consider being more specific than "does not work as expected", by saying (even now that your question has been answered) what specifically did you expect and what portion of this did not work.

Comment: Ok, I'll do better next time~

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Firstly: add an actual widget to your example:

```
    self.widget = QWidget(self)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(self.widget)
```

Secondly: do yourself a favour, and use triple-quotes:

```
    self.widget.setStyleSheet("""
        QWidget {
            border: 20px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }
        """)
```

The dot-selector in your example is redundant. What it does is specify that only instances of `QWidget` itself will be selected, as opposed to sub-classes of `QWidget`. See the [StyleSheet Syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) guide in the Qt docs.

Comment: For whatever reason, removing the dot-selector was the difference that made this work for me!

Answer (score 12):

In your project folder add a basic CSS file mystylesheet.css. Mutli-language editors like Atom are best for this type of things. The syntax highlighting works properly if you keep it named a CSS file.

Then drop the dot; qt knows what you mean.

mystylesheet.css

```css
QWidget {
    border: 20px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```py
anyQelement.setStyleSheet(open('mystylesheet.css').read())
```

Comment: Would it be better to use     
with open("mystylesheet.css", 'r') as file:
    sheet = file.read()
anyQelement.setStyleSheet(sheet)
to ensure the file is closed properly?