# Manipulating SVG Data in PyQt QMainWindow setStyleSheet- function

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qmainwindow

I'm working on a UI in PyQt and I want to add a background-image to the MainWindow.
Adding the Picture is not the problem, but if I run my code the image is shown multiple times...

Here is a short codesnipped:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *

    class BackgroundIssue(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            super().__init__(parent)

            self.setWindowTitle(f'Background Issue')
            self.setMinimumSize(1000, 800)
            self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(max.svg);")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = BackgroundIssue()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can see my output here:
[My Output Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFcFJ.png)

Does anyone know how to manipulate the picture inside .setStyleSheet to set it to the center of my window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I've found a solution by myself...

My problem was that I didn't knew about the CSS part in setStyleSheet.

[How to apply style sheet to a custom widget in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504421/how-to-apply-style-sheet-to-a-custom-widget-in-pyqt)

So my previous code needs to be changed like this:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *

    class BackgroundIssue(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            super().__init__(parent)

            self.setWindowTitle(f'Background Issue')
            self.setMinimumSize(1000, 800)
            self.setStyleSheet("""  background-image: url(max.png);
                                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                    background-position: center center;
            """)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        main_window = BackgroundIssue()
        main_window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the final view:

[image: centered background image]

Comment: Please clarify what you actually did to solve your issue, since the question you link is only related in concept, not in practical solution.

Comment: hey @musicamante, thanks for your response. I've edited my answer, I hope it's more clear now.